# Qt: My Application doesn't show up in my enterprise HW while in pc does

Tags: c++, qt, device

I've made a couple of projects in Qt4.8.5 which have to run on a especific device (the product of our company) which runs under a unix OS and they run normal. You launch them, they show up and you use them.

Now I've made another program, which is like one of the before mentioned but bigger. The thing is that now that I've finished it, I've tried to run it on the HW and something strange happened:

The screen gets black (the tipical black "with light" that means that the screen is on). I've launched it manually so I can see the console messages on console and I see all the qDebug() it has to print at the beginning and also, I have a `qDebug() << "1st page";` on the `::initializePage()`funcion of the first page shown (is a QWizardPage) also which is printed, so everything looks normal but... I can't see it on the screnn... just a black screen (My apps' background is orange so it is now the background of the app).

Any idea of why I can't see it? The HW has all the libraries necessaries for it because as I said, I run there  2 other Qt apps.

I add my .pro info...don't think it is usefull now but... any information is apreciated I guess..

```
QT       += core gui
QT       += network
QT       += script
QT       += date
QT       += time
QT       += xml
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS  += -s

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = MyApp
TEMPLATE = app
```

Thank you so much.

**Note:** In the 1st page I have 2 buttons, so if you press enter, you go to the next QWizardPage called 2nd page so... when I see the "1st page" message on console, if I press enter on the device, of course, it then shows the "2nd page" message from the qDebug in the ::initializePage() which means that the program runs well, it is not frozen.

Another thing I want to point is that: it  CAN'T be in the background running, the device make it appear in front always.

Comment: In Qt4, setting QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 in the environment is very helpful for logging if you are using any of the plugins. Is this a multi head (monitor) system ?

Comment: @prabindh  thanks for your answer. I don't use pluigns I think and no, its not a multi head monitor. is just ..lets say is a monitor (normal monitor with a specific computer).

Comment: Can you add an animating widget, instead of waiting for user input ?

Comment: @prabindh would be the same result.. my problem is that I can't see my program... it is running but I can't see. I don't even see  the background... but it is launchedand working O.o

Comment: Unless a minimum reproducible code is posted, it is difficult to proceed further. Please check if it is possible.

Comment: @prabindh I know its difficult but there isn't any code I think can be involved in that problem.so.. I asked that question hoping someone had some idea of what can happen.. or if it happened before to someone because I tried to google it before ofc, and found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... after 2 days looking and trying different things with the different versions I had in the SVN I've found the stupid-silly-cause of my problem...

It was a page, more exactly in its constructor where I create a connect between a combobox curretnIndexChanged signal and a fucntion I created as a slot. After that connect I load some items into the cb and switching those lines fixed my problem.... I don't really understand why because the combobox was well created and I thought is was not necessary to load some items into it to be able to do a connect with it  but... seems I was wrong (ofc, if not I won't be here posting that problem :P)

So.. thank you everybody for your help :)